# How to get the file path of a file inside the C# Assembly project of a Web API2 project

Tags: c#, filepath

I am trying to get a file path inside C# Assembly project of a Web API 2 project.
I have 2 projects Web (i-e the API) and Services (i-e the C# Library). Inside my Service.cs file of Services project I wan't to read the file from a folder call "FileFolder" (Services and FileFolder are at same level inside my Services project). Is there any way of retrieving the file path from within the same executing project folder or if there is a way to get the Solution absolute path so that I can append my C# library project/Folder/FileName?

Comment: what did you try? do you mean runtime path awareness, as in System.Reflection.Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().Codebase and the like?

Comment: I have tried HostingEnvironment.MapPath but it gives me the web project (i-e the API project) file path. Also have tried through GetExecutingAssembly but couldn't get it working

Comment: Referenced assemblies are copied into the bin folder of the executing application. You are not going to be able to get a path to your other project, that is not how it works at runtime.